# Yii::$app->user->isGuest always true on main.php after login

Tags: yii2

I want to implement user login into yii2 basic app.everything works properly except, when I tries to access `Yii::$app->user->isGuest` on layout main page. it always returns true. whats going wrong here?, please help me

```
 public function actionLogin()
    {
        if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
            return $this->goHome();
        }

        $model = new LoginForm();

        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) { 
            Yii::$app->user->isGuest;  // i m getting this as false, which is correct, but after goBack(), I m getting it as true
            return $this->goBack();
        }
        return $this->render('login', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

**Login Mehod from LoginForm.php**

```
 public function login()
    {
        if ($this->validate()) { 
            return Yii::$app->user->login($this->getUser(), $this->rememberMe ? 3600*24*30 : 0);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Note : I am using custom theme, which rests outside the `web` folder and inside `project/themes/` directory

** User Model is as follows**

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\behaviors\TimestampBehavior;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;
use yii\web\NotFoundHttpException;

class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface {

    private $id;
    private $authKey;

    const STATUS_DELETED = '0';
    const STATUS_ACTIVE = '10';

    public static function tableName() {
        return '{{%user}}';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function behaviors() {
        return [
            TimestampBehavior::className(),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId() {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey() {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey) {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return boolean if password provided is valid for current user
     */

    public function validatePassword($password) {
        return Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash);
    }


    public static function findByEmail($email) {
        $user_type = ['U'];
        return static::find()
                        ->andWhere('email = :email', [':email' => $email])
                        ->andFilterWhere(['in', 'user_type', $user_type])
                        ->one();
    }

    public static function findIdentity($id) {
        $user = static::find()->where(['id' => $id, 'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,])->one();
        if (empty($user->id)) {
            \Yii::$app->session->destroy();
        }
        return $user;
    }

    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null) {

        $user = static::find()
                ->where([
                    'access_token' => $token,
                    'status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
                ])
                ->one();
        if (!empty($user)) {
            return $user;
        } else {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Invalid access token.');
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So you check its value in layout file or inside this `actionLogin`?

Comment: inside login i m getting it as false, but after redirect  to layout/main.php its getting true

Comment: Show us `login()` method from `LoginForm`.

Comment: I have not modified it. Please refer updated code

Comment: Not sure how to help... Have you modified `User` model in any way?

Comment: Yes I have modified it to use my database table

Comment: Ok, so let me see your `User` model in this case.

Comment: Have u declare `User`model in web.php in components section like this  `'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,  ?
        ],`

Comment: @Mohan : Yes I have declared it ,with `enableAutoLogin` as `false`

Comment: And `['identityClass'=>'app\models\User]'`

Comment: First of all remove `private $id; private $authKey;` from `User` and check again. This `if (empty($user->id)) { \Yii::$app->session->destroy(); }` is not needed as well.

Comment: @Bizley : Thanks alot, its woking now, can you please elaborate what was the reason behind this. I just removed `private $id; private $authKey;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
private $id;
private $authKey;
```

from `User` class.

You should not directly declare ActiveRecord attributes that come from database as stated in the [Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#accessing-data).

> **Note**: The Active Record attributes are named after the associated table columns in a case-sensitive manner. Yii automatically defines an attribute in Active Record for every column of the associated table. You should NOT redeclare any of the attributes.